# How to safely pass parameters into MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Tags: maui

```
lock (locker )
{
    ...    
    string newLabelText = GetNewText ();
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( () =>
    {
        label.Text = newLabelText;
    });
    return;
}
```

Here, there would seem to be a risk that newLabelText could be taken out of scope before being consumed. A way would be needed to wait for the main thread code to complete, before returning. However, await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync can't be used as we are inside a lock.

Sharing below the solution I found.

Comment: *A variable that is captured won't be garbage-collected until the delegate that references it becomes eligible for garbage collection.* from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void BeginInvokeOnMainThreadAndWait ( Action action )
{
    ManualResetEventSlim resetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim ( false );
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread ( () =>
    {
        action.Invoke ();
        resetEvent.Set ();
    });

    resetEvent.Wait ();
    resetEvent.Dispose ();
}

...

string newLabelText = GetNewText ();
BeginInvokeOnMainThreadAndWait ( () =>
{
    label.Text = newLabelText;
});
return;
```